# Change JQuery Raty ReadOnly value after user click

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to make Raty read-only in the click event, but it does not work:

```
            $('#number').raty({
            click: function(score, evt) {
                readOnly: true; //it does not work here
                $.get(
                "../../ajax/test.aspx",
                {r:score},
                function (data) { alert(data); },
                "html"
        );

                },
            scoreName: 'entity.score',
            number: 10

            });
```

[Raty Home Page](http://www.wbotelhos.com/raty/#action-demo)

Comment: Add a reference to the plug-in source so we can avoid massive searching please. and markup would also help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to unbind the click events on the `img`

```
$('#star').raty({
    click: function(score, evt) {
        $(this).find('img').unbind('click');
        // $(this).find('img').unbind(); <-- this removes all listeners
    }
});
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xnZVd/

Comment: Care to elaborate what doesn't work? If you mean that you can't see the stars, it's because I can't upload images to JSFiddle. I've also added a new example here using your IDs: http://jsfiddle.net/xnZVd/1/

Comment: I added `$(this).find('img').unbind('click');` but still I can rate.

Comment: I've only removed the click event, which sends the rating. If you want to remove everything (i.e. stars changing when you hover over them), you can try `$(this).find('img').unbind();` . I've also added a full blown example at http://sandbox.compile.ch

Comment: thanks @Khôi :) please also add your comment in answer, its valuable ;)